# Best way to typeset Euler's method

Tags: tables, math-mode, formatting

I need to typset my calculations for several iterations of Euler's method and I'm having trouble depicting it in a way that is easy to read. Here is what I have now:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    $n$ & $t_n$ & $y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})$                          & $y_n = y_{n-1} + (t_n - t_{n-1})y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})$  \\\midrule
    1 & 0       & --                                             & 1 \\
    2 & 0.2     & $-2\cdot1+1-e^0 = -2$                          & $1 + 0.2(-2) = 0.6$  \\
    3 & 0.4     & $-2\cdot0.6+ 1 - e^{-4\cdot0.2} \approx -0.65$ &   $0.6 + 0.2(-0.65) = 0.47$\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Euler's method table]
I would appreciate any suggestions on how to make this table more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the only thing that's making the above hard to read is spacing between rows and arrays. I think a little moderation should fix it (NOTE: I adjusted the size of your table with `\scalebox` so it fits, hence the `graphicx` package):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \def\arraystretch{2}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{23pt}

    \begin{center}
    \scalebox{0.7}{
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
        \toprule
        $n$ & $t_n$ & $y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})$                          & $y_n = y_{n-1} + (t_n - t_{n-1})y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})$  \\\midrule
        1 & 0       & --                                             & 1 \\
        2 & 0.2     & $-2\cdot1+1-e^0 = -2$                          & $1 + 0.2(-2) = 0.6$  \\
        3 & 0.4     & $-2\cdot0.6+ 1 - e^{-4\cdot0.2} \approx -0.65$ &   $0.6 + 0.2(-0.65) = 0.47$\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope my post was helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The following fits in a standard text width, but I also suggest how to make the table a bit smaller.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\[
\begin{array}{@{} c c c c @{}}
\toprule
n & t_n & y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1}) & y_n = y_{n-1} + (t_n - t_{n-1})y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})
\\
\midrule
1 & 0   & -                                            & 1 \\
\addlinespace
2 & 0.2 & -2\cdot1+1-e^0 = -2                          & 1 + 0.2(-2) = 0.6  \\
\addlinespace
3 & 0.4 & -2\cdot0.6+ 1 - e^{-4\cdot0.2} \approx -0.65 & 0.6 + 0.2(-0.65) = 0.47 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
X\dotfill X
\[
\mbox{\small$\begin{array}{@{} c c c c @{}}
\toprule
n & t_n & y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1}) & y_n = y_{n-1} + (t_n - t_{n-1})y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})
\\
\midrule
1 & 0   & -                                            & 1 \\
\addlinespace
2 & 0.2 & -2\cdot1+1-e^0 = -2                          & 1 + 0.2(-2) = 0.6  \\
\addlinespace
3 & 0.4 & -2\cdot0.6+ 1 - e^{-4\cdot0.2} \approx -0.65 & 0.6 + 0.2(-0.65) = 0.47 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$}
\]

\end{document}
```

If you have several of these tables and some don't fit, it's probably better to define a suitable environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{sizedarray}{O{}+b}
 {\mbox{#1$\begin{array}#2\end{array}$}}
 {}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\[
\begin{sizedarray}{@{} c c c c @{}}
\toprule
n & t_n & y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1}) & y_n = y_{n-1} + (t_n - t_{n-1})y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})
\\
\midrule
1 & 0   & -                                            & 1 \\
\addlinespace
2 & 0.2 & -2\cdot1+1-e^0 = -2                          & 1 + 0.2(-2) = 0.6  \\
\addlinespace
3 & 0.4 & -2\cdot0.6+ 1 - e^{-4\cdot0.2} \approx -0.65 & 0.6 + 0.2(-0.65) = 0.47 \\
\bottomrule
\end{sizedarray}
\]
X\dotfill X
\[
\begin{sizedarray}[\small]{@{} c c c c @{}}
\toprule
n & t_n & y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1}) & y_n = y_{n-1} + (t_n - t_{n-1})y'(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})
\\
\midrule
1 & 0   & -                                            & 1 \\
\addlinespace
2 & 0.2 & -2\cdot1+1-e^0 = -2                          & 1 + 0.2(-2) = 0.6  \\
\addlinespace
3 & 0.4 & -2\cdot0.6+ 1 - e^{-4\cdot0.2} \approx -0.65 & 0.6 + 0.2(-0.65) = 0.47 \\
\bottomrule
\end{sizedarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

[image]